# how to make _.includes method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a junior developer who has been coding for 4 weeks.

I'm working on a JavaScript method.

I'll show you the code I used first.

```js
_.each = function (collection, iteratee) {
  if(Array.isArray(collection)===true){
    for(let i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
      iteratee(collection[i],i,collection)
    }
  }else{
  let objvalues= Object.values(collection)
  let objkeys = Object.keys(collection)
  for(let i=0;i<objvalues.length;i++){
    iteratee(objvalues[i],objkeys[i],collection)
  }
}
};
```

```js
_.includes = function (arr, target) {
    let result
    _.each(arr, function(a){
      if(a === target) 
        result = true
      if (a !== target)
        result = false
      
    })
    return result;
};
```

It's a condition.

If the _.include method matches the value found by the element in the array, the true must be returned.

If the element in the array does not match the value you are looking for, you must return false.

I made the _include method.

If the element in the array does not match the value you are looking for, the return to false is successful.ten thousand

If the element in the array matches the value you are looking for, you must return true

This is where you fail.

It seems that the ture cannot be returned and only false is returned.

How should I handle this?

Comment: How have you defined `_`?

Comment: have you tried using a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)?

Comment: my comment might be off but I suggest you to use JavaScript's array methods like includes() and forEach() instead of making your own implementation. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
_.each(arr, function(a){
  if(a === target) 
    result = true
  if (a !== target)
    result = false
})
```

You reassign `result` on every iteration. As a result, the only iteration that matters for the final value of `result` is the last iteration.

Instead, initialize `result` to `false`, and reassign to `true` when the target is found:

```js
const _ = {};
_.each = function(collection, iteratee) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection) === true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      iteratee(collection[i], i, collection)
    }
  } else {
    let objvalues = Object.values(collection)
    let objkeys = Object.keys(collection)
    for (let i = 0; i < objvalues.length; i++) {
      iteratee(objvalues[i], objkeys[i], collection)
    }
  }
};
_.includes = function(arr, target) {
  let result = false;
  _.each(arr, function(a) {
    if (a === target)
      result = true
  })
  return result;
};

console.log(
  _.includes([1, 2, 3], 2)
);
```

It'd be cleaner to break the loop once a match is found, but your `_each` isn't set up for that:

```js
const _ = {};
_.each = function(collection, iteratee) {
  if (Array.isArray(collection) === true) {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      iteratee(collection[i], i, collection)
    }
  } else {
    let objvalues = Object.values(collection)
    let objkeys = Object.keys(collection)
    for (let i = 0; i < objvalues.length; i++) {
      iteratee(objvalues[i], objkeys[i], collection)
    }
  }
};
_.includes = function(arr, target) {
  for (const a of arr) {
    if (a === target)
      return true
  }
  return false;
};

console.log(
  _.includes([1, 2, 3], 2)
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks to you, I was able to solve the problem. I could see for sure where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what **CertainPerfomance** already said, you could see how **Array.includes** was implemented to get an inspiration, here is the specifications from [TC39](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.includes).